# Как сделать unsigned right\left shift для байта?

Tags: java

Прошу простить за вопрос, который казалось бы, можно решить с помощью Oracle-доки, но у меня не получается. Я новичок в Java. Прошу помочь делом и ткнуть в место, что конкретно я не понимаю?

Мне нужно написать операции с байтам rol\ror и столкнулся с тем что не совсем понимаю, как работать с битами в Java. Ниже тесты показывают то что хочу получить.

```
static void test1() {
    int i = 0x80;
    int i1 = i >> 1;
    int i2 = i >>> 1;
    System.out.println(String.format("i: %02X", (byte)i));
    System.out.println(String.format("i1: %02X", (byte)i1));
    System.out.println(String.format("i2: %02X", (byte)i2));
}

static void test2() {
    byte b = (byte)0x80;
    byte b1 = (byte)((int)(b) >> 1);
    byte b2 = (byte)((int)(b) >>> 1);
    System.out.println(String.format("b: %02X", b));
    System.out.println(String.format("b1: %02X", b1));
    System.out.println(String.format("b2: %02X", b2));
}
```

В результате получаю:

```
i: 80
i1: 40
i2: 40
b: 80
b1: C0
b2: C0
```

Как видно в test2() leftmost бит проставляется в единицу, а ожидаю в 0. Ожидаю согласно доке [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). В доке четко сказано:

```
The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.
```

Вопрос: Почему в test2() несмотря на то что я работаю с int , все равно получаю 0xC0?
Вопрос №2: Возможно я пишу велосипед и подобные операции уже есть и я о них не знаю?

Comment: 0xC0 вы получаете за счет приведения к типу byte. Если убрать приведение типа, то вы получите 0xFFFFFFC0 и 0x7FFFFFC0 соответственно.

Comment: @a_gura: Вы правы! Но пока что-то не вижу способа как "двигать" байты?

Comment: @sys_dev Я как бы намекаю на то, что вы смотрите не на тот бит. Что по-вашему такое leftmost bit? Какой индекс у этого бита?

Comment: @a_gura: Я отлично понял Ваш намек, но это пока никак не прибавило мне понимания как на Java "циклически двигать байты"? Пока вижу что  unsigned сдвиг возможен только для int типов и как без мазохизма "двинуть байты" не понятно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена:

```
public static byte ror(byte b, int bits) {
    int bits_ = bits % 8;
    int v = b & 0xFF;
    byte result = (byte) ((v << (8 - bits_)) | (v >>> bits_));
    return result;
}

public static byte rol(byte b, int bits) {
    int bits_ = bits % 8;
    int v = b & 0xFF;
    byte result = (byte) ((v << bits_) | (v >>> (8 - bits_)));
    return result;
}
```